Trying to get Gizmo to change color when touching game objects
i am trying to make my gizmos change color when they touch a game object with the layer obstacle. however for some reason the gizmos aren't spawning in and getting error  'object reference not set to an instance of an object'
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Grid : MonoBehaviour

{
    Node[,] grid;
    [SerializeField] int width = 25;
    [SerializeField] int length = 25;
    [SerializeField] float cellSize = 1f;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask obstacleLayer;

    private void Start()
    {
        GenerateGrid();
    }

    private void GenerateGrid()
    {
        grid = new Node[length, width];
        CheckPassableTerrain();
    }

    private void CheckPassableTerrain()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
            {
                Vector3 worldPosition = GetWorldPosition(x, y);
                bool passable = !Physics.CheckBox(worldPosition, Vector3.one * cellSize, Quaternion.identity, obstacleLayer);
                grid[x, y] = new Node();
                grid[x, y].passable = passable;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (grid == null)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
                {
                    
                    Vector3 pos = GetWorldPosition(x, y);
                    Gizmos.color = grid[x, y].passable ? Color.white : Color.red;
                    Gizmos.DrawCube(pos, Vector3.one );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GetWorldPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        return new Vector3(transform.position.x + (x * cellSize), 0.5f, transform.position.z + (y * cellSize));
    }

}


i tried changing the line to gizmos.color = color.red which does spawn the gizmos in which makes me think its something to do with the grid defaulting to null. which i also don't know how to fix.
changed onDrawGizmos too
private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (grid != null)
        {
            
            for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
                {
                    
                    Vector3 pos = GetWorldPosition(x, y);
                    if (grid[x, y].passable)
                    {
                        Gizmos.color = Color.white;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
                    }
                    Gizmos.DrawCube(pos, Vector3.one );
                }
            }
        }
    }



In OnDrawGizmos you do check
if (grid == null)

and if this is the case then you try to access it in
Gizmos.color = grid[x, y].passable ? Color.white : Color.red;

=> That doesn't make much sense to me. The check should probably rather read
if (grid != null)


Whether you rather want to lazy initialize the grid already in the editor is up to you - you could do so in OnValidate so it would be updated every time you modify a value (like width, height, cellSize) in the Inspector.

So now that you revealed you actually do need this in the editor rather then during play mode I think you could use ExecuteAlways and then
void Awake()
{
    GenerateGrid();
}

void Update()
{
    if(! Application.isPlaying) GenerateGrid();
}

This will now regenerate the grid whenever anything is changed in the scene.

So i did do that and even changed the code a bit. its still doesnt spawn the gizmos in sadly but turns out running GenerateGrid; right before ondrawgizmos makes it work. but spawns the gizmos endlessly. so i need something like onvalidate to call GrenerateGrid; but also call it when i move it in the editor

Ok so i did try your new suggestion and for some reason the grid still isnt generating. I tried running a debug and it tells me that the script you wrote is working but when ondrawgizmos is called its forcing grid to become null again.

So I wonder if onDrawGizmos is being called before grid is set?

I haven't worked with this Node class before but the reason why you are getting null reference exceptions might be because you haven't initialized you grid class on when you declare it and you have initialized it in the Start function.
The start function runs when you play your game. but OnDrawGizmos can run while you're in the editor too. just write this in your declaration
Node[,] grid = new Node[length, width];

hope it helps

Sure he does, in Start.

yeah that is already called at the start. however i did try what you suggested but still didnt work.
